# how i install mssqlcli on my windows 7 machine.

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005

How can I install ms sql client on my windows 7 machine ? 
Because without this driver error is "Provider cannot be found"

I am using mssql server 2005 on my Win XP, I am fail to install dot net framework 2 on windows 7 client.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maintaining a system and not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Native Client contains the SQL OLE DB provider and SQL ODBC driver in one native dynamic link library (DLL) supporting applications using native-code APIs (ODBC, OLE DB and ADO) to Microsoft SQL Server.

Get the SQL Server Native Client for SQL Server 2005

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793